# Publishing free android applications on android market for unsupported countries

Tags: android

I am aware that selling applications on android market is not yet supported in my country "India" as per this link [Supported locations for merchants to sell paid apps.](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324)

But as per [Supported locations for free publishers](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136758), I should be able to publish free apps.

However, when I try to register on Android Developer Console, on screen "Developer Distribution Agreement" where i need to accept the Terms and Conditions, there is no option to select my country "India" in the drop-down.

I just need to publish free apps. :(

> My question is-
>
> If there's any developer from unsupported countries who has already
>   register, which country did you selected on the terms and conditions
>   page("Read and agree to the Developer Distribution Agreement.")?

I also tried mailing google help center...but they just give an automated standard reply which is not helping me.

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDITED:
This is the page where i need to select country:(India is not listed here)
[image]

Comment: click it and request access to chat  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10629/agarwal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Language selector is for displaying the license agreement in some other language. It has nothing to do with publishing free applications. It doesn't matter what language you are going to select there. So accept the license agreement and proceed, you will be able to publish your application.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Are you sure it is for the language selection? Initially i also thought so.. but than it seems that its country-wise terms and conditions, and the checkbox at the bottom says "I am willing to account registration with the developer Distributioon Agreement"

Comment: Here are the [countries allowed to distribute free applications](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138294). You still have to pay 25$ for registration though.

Comment: yes..I did checked that earlier. All i am concerned about, is the "terms and conditions" page in the screenshot in my earlier post. I did wrote to google help center also, but no reply from them :( Is your country listed in the drop-down above?

Comment: Yes it is (GREECE) but When I registered with them I never read the agreement, I just hit "I Agree", payed the 25$ and publish my app (tatoggles widget). That was last year and I had to accept a new agreement (again never read it) about 3 months ago (via e-mail) in order to continue using my account. If you are in concern about the agreement then you have to wait for their answer but it may take days. P.S. I know it isn't good not to read the agreements but I am from Greece, we never read agreements we just sign and cry afterwards :)

Comment: haha... I am gonna mail google for couple more days and then probably might give up and follow what you did. ;) ... It does makes sense as there is no other way I can register as free publisher... thanks a lot :)

Comment: Now you 've got the point! No matter what you think about the agreement Google rules! There is nothing you can do, either you agree with whatever they want or you are out of the "game". Anyway good luck with your "Google Play" quest, I am glad that my thoughts helped you out...